# "this kernel requires a x86-64 CPU but only detected an i686CPU." when installing Ubuntu on Virtualbox

Tags: boot, virtualbox

While trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 I have this message:

```
this kernel requires a x86-64 CPU but only detected an i686CPu.
Unable to boot  use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Sounds like your cpu isnt a 64-bit one. Try to install the 32-Bit version and not the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 0):

Go here [ubuntu 32bit](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and click on the drop down menu and choose to install ubuntu 32bit it is the one you need for your computer because it is a 32bit  computer.[image]